# DataGridView and values from multiple tables?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

On one of my WinForms I have to use a DataGridView control that shows data from a DB table. In that table there are few foreign keys, so my DGV looks like this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | ForeignKey1 | ForeignKey2 | ...
================================================...
Text    | Text    | 1           | 1           | ...
```

Is there a way to show the values that are referenced by foreign keys somehow?

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve and what do you mean by "referenced" and where do you want to show those values?

Comment: There are multiple solutions for such requirement. What's the data source of grid?

Comment: you can do it by modifying your query by which you are getting the data.Add your query so i could modify it

Comment: A possible solution could be [Master-Detail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8c0cxey(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Of course it is. You can show whatever data in each particular cell of your gridview as long as it's convertable to text formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the following approach:

Let your `tbl1` has columns:

```
stu_id (primary key),
stu_name
```

Let your `tbl2` has columns:

```
course_id (primary key),
course_name
```

Then your `tbl3` has columns:

```
teacher, 
stu_id (foreign key),
course_id (foreign key)
```

Now you can  print the data from `tbl3` with foreign keys as:

```
select teacher,
(select stu_name from tbl1 where stu_id=tbl3.stu_id) stu_name ,
(select course_name from tbl2 where course_id=tbl3.course_id) course_name
 from tbl3;
```

Just get the data from the above approach in a `Datatable` and give the `GridView` Datasource.

Except it there are other so many ways you can do it.